# Can I contribute money to a 401k, 457b, and an IRA all at the same time?

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan, limits

I am a retiree who is returning to full time work.  Can I contribute the maximum to my full time job's 401(k) and to my part time job's 457(b)?  And then also contribute the maximum to an IRA?

Answer (score 8):

Many times the best info is from the IRS: [How Much Salary Can You Defer if You’re Eligible for More than One Retirement Plan?](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/How-Much-Salary-Can-You-Defer-if-You%E2%80%99re-Eligible-for-More-than-One-Retirement-Plan%3F)

> The amount of salary deferrals you can contribute to retirement plans
>   is your individual limit each calendar year no matter how many plans
>   you're in. This limit must be aggregated for these plan types:
>
> ```
> 401(k)
> 403(b)
> SIMPLE plans (SIMPLE IRA and SIMPLE 401(k) plans)
> SARSEP
> ```
>
> If you’re in a 457(b) plan, you have a separate limit that includes both employee and employer contributions.

Regarding having a 457 and another plan:

> Example 
>   You’re in a 457(b) and a 403(b) plan, each plan allows the
>   maximum deferrals for 2013 and you have enough includible
>   compensation. You may be able to defer:
>
> - $17,500 to each plan, regardless of your age
> - $23,000 to the 403(b) plan and $17,500 to the 457(b) plan if you’re age 50 or older > by the end of 2013 and the 403(b) plan allows age-50 catch-ups
> - $23,000 to each plan if you’re in a governmental 457(b) plan and both plans allow > age-50 catch-ups
> - $23,000 to the 403(b) plan if it allows and you’re eligible to make age-50 catch-up, and $35,000 to the 457(b) plan if it allows
>     catch-up contributions and you’re eligible for the last 3-year
>     catch-up.
> - an additional $3,000 to the 403(b), if you’ve worked for a qualified organization at least 15 years and the plan terms allow
>     these catch-ups.